# Scala - "if(true) Some(1)" without having to type "else None"

Tags: scala

In scala, if you have an Option, you can get another Option by doing oldOption.map(_.something). What I want to do is take a boolean and do the same thing. In other words, I want shorthand for the following:

```
if(someCondition)
  Some(data)
else
  None
```

Is there an idiomatic way to get an Option out of a Boolean like this without having to do "else None"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Scalaz has this.  The code would look like this:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
val b = true  
val opt = b option "foo"
```

The type of `opt` will be `Option[String]`

Answer (score 18):

If you don't mind creating the data every time,

```
Some(data).filter(someCondition)
```

will do the trick.  If you do mind creating the data every time,

```
Option(someCondition).filter(_ == true).map(_ => data)
```

but I don't think that's any clearer.  I'd go with if-else if I were you.

Or you could

```
def onlyIf[A](p: Boolean)(a: => A) = if (p) Some(a) else None
```

and then

```
onlyIf(someCondition){ data }
```

Comment: One small change: `Option(someCondition).filter(identity).map(_ => data)`

Comment: @pedrofurla - I find the comparison to true more informative than an identity filter.  I grant that identity may be more efficient, but if you're after efficiency you wouldn't write it this way at all.

Comment: I love the `onlyIf` method, but I wish it could be added to a new `Some` object in `scala.lang`. Then you could do `Some.onlyIf(x % 2 ==  0)(x)` to return an `Option[Int]`. This is really only useful, though, when the thing in the `Some` is rather complicated, which I can see doing as `Some.onlyIf(cond) { // lots of code here }}`.

Comment: @TOB - `implicit class SomeOnlyIf(val some: Some.type) extends AnyVal { def onlyIf[A](p: Boolean)(a: => A) = if (p) Some(a) else None }`

Answer (score 3):

How about playing with the fire:

```
implicit class CondOpt[T](x: => T) {
  def someIf(cond: Boolean) = if (cond) Some(x) else None
}
```

Use:

```
data someIf someCondition
```

Drawbacks:

1. Dangerous, implicit conversion from `Any`
2. <del>Calculates data every time</del>

Comment: Make the parameter call-by-name and it won't calculate the data unless it needs it. i.e. `implicit class CondOpt[T](x: => T)`

Comment: @LuigiPlinge Thanks, I changed it. Indeed since it is only a parameter (not a class value) it can be by-name.

Answer (score 2):

```
import PartialFunction._
condOpt(someCondition) {
  case true => data
}
```

Personally I use this pattern a lot when I need to extract something, e.g.

```
val maybeInt: Option[Int] = condOpt(string) {
  case AsInt(i) if i > 0 => i
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala 2.13 has [Option.when](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.13.x/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#when[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A])(someCondition)(dataExpression) and its corollary [Option.unless](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.13.x/api/2.13.x/scala/Option$.html#unless[A](cond:Boolean)(a:=%3EA):Option[A])

https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/44d08f68eb88c83a803eda240b6fdb18450aa8af

Answer (score 1):

in Scala 2.13 you could use `Option.when()`

```
Option.when(true)(data)
```

or you could use the opposite of it, which is `Option.unless()`

```
Option.unless(false)(data)
```