# Idiomatic alternative to `if (x) Some(y) else None`

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I'm finding the following pattern popping up repeatedly in my code, and my intuition says there must be some idiomatic Scala way to better express this (Monadic or otherwise):

```
val someCollection: Seq[Thing] = ...
val makeBlah: Seq[Thing] => Blah = ...
...
if (someCollection.nonEmpty) Some(makeBlah(someCollection)) else None
```

To be more specific, I'm looking for something along the lines of what you can do with `Option[T]`:

```
val someOption: Option[Thing] = ...
val makeBlah: Thing => Blah = ...
...
val result: Option[Blah] = someOption.map(makeBlah)
```

...but with evaluation semantics based on some predicate rather than `Some`/`None` pattern matching in `map`.

While the example above uses a collection--first performing a test on it, optionally followed by an operation--I don't mean to imply a collections specific use case. You could imagine a case where `Boolean` is lifted or coerced into some monad:

```
val aThing: Thing = ...
val makeBlah: Thing => Blah = ...
val thingTest: Thing => Boolean ...
// theoretical
implicit def optionOnBoolean(b: Boolean): MonadOps[Option[Boolean]] = ... 
...
// NB: map could either have a Boolean parameter
//     that's always true, or be Unit.
//     Neither seem like good design 
val result: Option[Blah] = thingTest(aThing).map(makeBlah(aThing))
```

Intuitively this seems like a bad idea to me because it explicitly splits the data flow since you don't really have anything to pass via `map`.

When looking for a general approach that has "monadic-like" behavior without a closure to capture data, one has to answer the question of what to pass to `map` and how its connection to the predicate. Here's the type of construct that comes to mind:

```
val thing: Thing = ....
val makeBlah: Thing => Blah = ...
val thingTest: (Thing) => Boolean = ...
val result: Option[Blah] = WhenOption(thing, thingTest).map(makeBlah)
```

My question: Does something already exist in Scala proper, or does one have to venture out to Scalaz to get this sort of construct?

Or is there some other approach that is customary/idiomatic Scala?

**Edit**: My question is close to [Scala - "if(true) Some(1)" without having to type "else None"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16327056/296509) but I wish to address the issue of achieving it without a closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, I do the same thing you propose:

```
implicit class RichBoolean(val b: Boolean) extends AnyVal {
  def map[T](f: => T): Option[T] = if (b) Some(f) else None
  def flatMap[T](f: => Option[T]): Option[T] = if (b) f else None   
}
```

"map" doesn't feel right here, but I can't think of anything better. I really like this construct, it can really help keep the "flow" when doing a few consecutive operations on your data.

Comment: Thanks @Adam for this fragment, and affirmation that you too see value in "flow" in the context of similar operations. While the `Some(x).filterNot(y)` construct @ziggystar points out isn't perhaps as clear to a novice, it doesn't require any extra code or libraries, which can be helpful in some contexts (e.g. quick REPL experiments).

Answer (score 5):

For completeness:

```
val someCollection: Seq[Thing] = ...
val makeBlah: Seq[Thing] => Blah = ...
```

You can use some methods on `Option`:

```
Some(someCollection).filterNot(_.isEmpty).map(makeBlah)
```

or as for comprehension

```
for(sc <- Some(someCollection) if !someCollection.isEmpty) yield makeBla(sc)
```

or as pattern match

```
someCollection match {
  case Seq() => None
  case x => Some(makeBlah(x))
}
```

But I think the `if-then-else` approach is the most readable one.

Comment: In my case I particularly like the `filterNot` approach you show, as it fits well within the types of function composition I'm doing, and where using the same pattern with `Option` as is done with collections aids in the readability.

Answer (score 3):

I would just continue doing what you're doing unless you find yourself repeating that same logic ad nauseum *within the same function scope*. It's readable and makes sense. That said, if you really need to, you can "lift" a `PartialFunction` (see [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.0/index.html#scala.PartialFunction)):

```
def foo: PartialFunction[Seq[A], B]

def fooLifted: (Seq[A] => Option[B]) = foo.lift
```

Now all you have to do is make your conditional logic explicit

```
def foo ={
  case seq if predicate(seq) => doStuff(seq)
}
```

This is a lot more boilerplate than what you're doing.

Comment: Pointing out the existence of `PartialFunction.lift` is very helpful. Thanks.